# remove a single <p> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my code, if the `<input>` is empty on blur, then a `<p>` containing a warning message is added with JavaScript. I remove the `<p>` when the `<input>` is focused again.

How can I do this without the `for` loop, since the `<div>` only has one `<p>`?
I'd like to do this with pure JavaScript (no jQuery).

```js
function produce_warning(message, div, inpt) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  para.setAttribute("class", "warning_msg");
  var node = document.createTextNode(message);
  para.appendChild(node);
  var element = document.getElementById(div);
  element.appendChild(para);
}

function remove_warning(div) {
  var element = document.getElementById(div).getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (var k = element.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    var item = element[k];
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-5" id="name_div">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="produce_warning('name', 'name_div')" onfocus="remove_warning('name_div')" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an alternative approach to working code. try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Look into the `querySelector` method.

Comment: Add `[0]` at the end?

Comment: Try query selector - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: @DanielA.White This is still **a specific problem/question** so this question is not at all off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `div` element will ever only have one `p` element, then you just have to target the first index of the array variable for removal:

```
function remove_warning(){
    // This returns an array
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    // Only one p element, so remove from the first index
    element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
}
```

Comment: it sounds like the OP might prefer "function remove_warning(div){" and "var element = document.getElementById(div).getElementsByTagName("p");". It looks like OP wants the first p in an element of ID div.

Comment: Thank you Lloyd Banks you solution works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Lloyd Banks's solution should work and is probably the best way to do it if you want to support older browsers. Modern browsers also support document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll.  querySelector / querySelectorAll let you select elements using CSS selectors. querySelectorAll will select all matching elements, while querySelector just selects the first one. So here's an alternative solution:

```
//pass the div id to this function,  for example "name_div"
function remove_warning(div){
    // This grabs the first p within the element with id div
    var element = document.querySelector("#"+div+" p");
    // go to element's parent and tell it to remove the element child
    // cause in javascript a child's gotta ask his parent
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Here's a list of browser compatibility for querySelector: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can do with just JavaScript but if you add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>` in your page somewhere you have access to Jquery. You would remove this `<p id = "removeThis">some text</p>` with this `<script> $("#removeThis").remove(); </script>`.

Comment: The OP stated that he wanted a solution in Javascript without jquery.

Comment: I said "I don't think you can do it with just JavaScript" I was just trying to help.

Comment: That's understandable although a comment would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @Adam how do you think jquery does this if javsacript cant? Jquery is just built on top of javascript. as unsolicited advice, it helps to learn native Javascript and DOM even if you're use using jquery :) You gain a better appreciation for why certain uses of jquery are faster/slower and recommended/not recommended... also jquery excels at DOM, but when you need to do other things, you might run into a situation where you need native javascript